# How to make customizer settings appear only when image is uploaded?

Tags: theme-customizer

I'm trying to replicate the WordPress core background image customizer settings where the styling settings/controls only appear when an image is uploaded, but can't find a way around it. Is there a hook of any sort to doing this?

```
$wp_customize->add_setting(
    'custom_background_size',
    array(
        'default'           => 'auto',
        'sanitize_callback' => '',
    )
);
$wp_customize->add_control(
    'custom_background_size',
    array(
        'label' => 'Background Size',
    'section' => 'background_image',
    'type' => 'radio',
    'choices' => array(
      'auto' => 'Auto (default)',
      'cover' => 'Cover'
    )
)
);
```

I've added a new custom setting/control for the background image size styling to the section . But doing only this will have it appear with or without an image uploaded.

Any help is really appreciated guys. Thanks!